# CSS - Bootstrap select dropdown styling color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am struggling to change default blue color for Bootstrap select dropdown.

I have tried `:hover`, `:active` over `option` and `select` without success.

What happens when user clicks on a select dropdown in Bootstrap? which would be the CSS selector to change:

1. the blue color when user hovers over all the options and
2. the border blue color that appears once the select is displayed (dropdowns)

[image: Bootstrap select dropdown]

The associated code is:

```
<select name="product_table_length" aria-controls="product_table" class="">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

I am using both Bootstrap and Datatables (not sure if the last one information is relevant or not).

Comment: quick peek into their demo shows that the background color is targeted by 
.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover {  
    color: #16181b;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    background-color: #f8f9fa;  
}

Comment: I guess it matters to know which version of bootstrap you're using

Comment: Bootstap 3.3.7, Datatables 1.10.16. At this time I am totally unsure on which library takes control of that particular element (it is part of a datatables table)

Comment: I have tried to redefine .dropdown-item without success. However it is worth to say that such classes do not appear while inspecting the elements with Google Inspectors

Answer (score 2):

The drowpdown list design of selects depends on the device. Each device has it's own design and the only way to change it is by adding javascript code allowing to customize it.

the aim is to make some html code such as a simple list which you'll design on your own. Then you create the real dropdown that you hide (or just an input hidden). When this is done, you create events in javascript with, for exemple, "onclick", that will change your hidden field value.

You can find an exemple on [codrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/)

Comment: As I have created no specific code for this, I am guessing that this is coming either from Bootstrap or Datatables, so any help regarding how to change default colors for this is welcomed.